# force website http:// to https://www asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web

I want to redirect non-www and non-https URLs to https://www for my domain, I actually have the following in web.config, that works ok redirecting non-https to https but still allows to access domain.com without www,

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Default to root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)default.aspx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I have shared hosting..

Comment: `www` is necessary for you?

Comment: it is necessary for search engine optimization . .. .

Comment: You need to add a third rule to analyze host name header and redirect.

Comment: @LexLi  got error message on third rool **This webpage has a redirect loop**

Comment: Post your third rule.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi Its running now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a running code

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Default to root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)default.aspx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
      <rule name="Add www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks @lexLi